# Replace values in None cells in Pandas with regular expression

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Could someone help me to solve one problem. I have a dataset, which contains restaurants and their addresses, and looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame (
data = [
    ['rest_1', 'city City_name, street Street, bld 1'],
    ['rest_2', 'city City_name, street Street Name, bld 2'],
    ['rest_3', 'City_name, street 1-st Street Name, building 2'],
    ['rest_4', 'city City_name, Street Name street, flat 1'],
    ['rest_5', 'City_name city, Streen Name avemue, flat 2'],
    ['rest_6', 'city City_name, bdr Street Name Second_name, flt 3'],
    ['rest_7', 'street Street, bld 3'],
    ['rest_8', 'Doublename Street street, building 4']
],
columns = ['restaurant', 'address']
)

print(df)
    restaurant  address
0   rest_1      city City_name, street Street, bld 1
1   rest_2      city City_name, street Street Name, bld 2
2   rest_3      City_name, street 1-st Street Name, building 2
3   rest_4      city City_name, Street Name street, flat 1
4   rest_5      City_name city, Streen Name avemue, flat 2
5   rest_6      city City_name, bdr Street Name Second_name, f...
6   rest_7      street Street, bld 3
7   rest_8      Doublename Street street, building 4
```

I need to create additional column with only street name. I've made a function with regular expression and applied it

```
def extract(street):
    try:
        street_name = re.search(',+[\w -№]*,',street).group()
        return street_name[1:-1]
    except:
        print(street)

df['street'] = df['address'].apply(extract)
```

the problem  is that addresses have different formats. And a few of them don`t contains city. So, as a result i get such table

```
print(df)   
    restaurant  address                                             street
0   rest_1      city City_name, street Street, bld 1                street Street
1   rest_2      city City_name, street Street Name, bld 2           street Street Name
2   rest_3      City_name, street 1-st Street Name, building 2      street 1-st Street Name
3   rest_4      city City_name, Street Name street, flat 1          Street Name street
4   rest_5      City_name city, Streen Name avemue, flat 2          Streen Name avemue
5   rest_6      city City_name, bdr Street Name Second_name, f...   bdr Street Name Second_name
6   rest_7      street Street, bld 3                                None
7   rest_8      Doublename Street street, building 4                None
```

How can I apply another regular expression only to None values cells in result dataframe and get the result such as

```
    restaurant  address                                                 street
0   rest_1      city City_name, street Street, bld 1                    street Street
1   rest_2      city City_name, street Street Name, bld 2               street Street Name
2   rest_3      City_name, street 1-st Street Name, building 2          street 1-st Street Name
3   rest_4      city City_name, Street Name street, flat 1  Street Name street
4   rest_5      City_name city, Streen Name avenue, flat 2  Streen Name avenue
5   rest_6      city City_name, bdr Street Name Second_name, f...   bdr Street Name Second_name
6   rest_7      street Street, bld 3                                    street Street
7   rest_8      Doublename Street street, building 4    Doublename      Doublename Street street
```

Will be thankful for any help!

Comment: What is `№`...?

Comment: It is a sing which means 'number' in Russian language )

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by simple cycle:

```
for i in df[df['street'].isnull()].index:
    data.loc[i,'street'] = re.search('^[\w -№]*,',data.loc[i,'address']).group()
```

and got the result I needed